# Degree of irrationality and hyperelliptic curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, hyperelliptic-curves

For a variety $V$ of dimension $n$, let $Irr(V)$ denote the minimal degree of a dominant rational map $V\to \mathbb{P}^n$.

Suppose that a curve $X$ admits a dominant map from a variety $V$ with $Irr(V)=2$.  Does it follow that $X$ is hyperelliptic?

Comment: Probably you want $Irr(V)$ to be the minimal degree of a **dominant** rational maps $V\to\mathbb P^n$.

Comment: @JoeSilverman: yes.

Comment: Degree of irrationality?  I thought that was called the gonality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, because then there is a nonconstant map from projective space to the symmetric square of $C$.

Comment: I see the map from projective space to the symmetric square of $C$ but how does it imply that $C$ is hyperelliptic?

Comment: One way to see it is to compose with the map from $C$ to its Jacobian.  That map *does* have to be constant, because that's true of every map from projective space to an abelian variety.  But then there are two distinct points in the symmetric square that map to the same point in the Jacobian.  So the difference between them is the divisor of a rational function.  That function has degree $2$.  So we have a degree-2 rational function on $C$, **QED**.